# trying to run a simple beginner function in javascript, not returning correctly

Tags: javascript, function, console

Here is the code I wrote;

```
var nameString = function(name) {
    console.log ("Hi, I am" + " " + name);

};
nameString("Bobby");
```

I am trying to get it to return one line stating;
Hi, I am Bobby

instead, it returns three:

> Hi, I am Bobby
>   Hi, I am
>   Hi, I am Bobby

I can't figure out why it is returning three times

Comment: You have called nameString three times.

Comment: It works fine for me, so I can only imagine that you are calling it trhee times somewhere...

Comment: Try alert does it do that too

Comment: Check in console , its return only Hi, I am Bobby

Comment: intead of pasting excerpt , paste the full code.

Comment: It's working fine , maybe you did mistake somewhere else ?

Comment: Sorry, this is actually the full code, which is why it is confusing me, its from a guide on codeacadamy, found here 
http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-6LzGd/2#!/exercises/2

using there script writer, I am thinking it is just a bug, since there really does not seem like anything is wrong with the code

Comment: Can you provide me full javascript code written in page.

Answer (score 1):

Codecademy runs the function 3 times for some reasons, basically to detect stuff and hint you on the right code... Each time outputing something in the console since you put `console.log`. Use `return` instead and it will work.

```
var nameString = function(name) {
    return "Hi, I am" + " " + name;

};
console.log(nameString("Bobby"));
```

Don't use the console in codecademy functions, it needs to be on the call..

Answer (score 0):

This on it self just renders the result just one time. Maybe it is nested in some code which ensures the three execution cycles...

Comment: it must be comment not answer dear.

Comment: he can not comment on the questions yet

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's the first time I see a function like yours (I'm not saying it be bad, I'm not a JavaScript expert)...

Try it:

```
function getNameString(name) {
  return "Hi, I am" + " " + name;
};
var nameString = getNameString("Bobby");
console.log(nameString);
```

I think your problem is that you are trying to put the returned value of a function as value of a variable. But really, your function does not return any value. So maybe it's causing this rare behavior that you tell us... Other approach more similar as yours:

```
var nameString = function(name) {
  return "Hi, I am" + " " + name;
};
nameString("Bobby");
console.log(nameString);
```

Comment: quoting myself: "I'm not saying it be bad, I'm not a JavaScript expert"

Comment: I understand. It does not explain or solve the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Use it:

```
var nameString = function(name) {
     return "Hi, I am" + " " + name;
};

var theName = prompt("What is your name?");
var result = nameString(theName);
console.log(result);
```